# Simple Socket Programming and thread with JDBC arraylist

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, jdbc, arraylist

I'm already taking some questions from database with JDBC, resultsets, etc... then putting this into arraylists.. and show all via Java GUI.

However now i want to extend this using sockets, threads etc.. to learn this staff.

This time i want to use three tier architecture approach, where the database access is
sorted in the application layer which interacts the same old database. 
Application layer is going to act like a server which accept incoming
requests of multiple clients and provide the interaction with the data level.

I try something like this;

Server side: taking questions(20 tf questions, 8 multiple), writing to arraylist and sends to the client.
I send only tf questions. How can i send also multiples ?

Is this true way to do this ? 
If threads are necessary ? How can i implement threads to this ?

```
public class trainingServer {

    static ArrayList<TrueFalse> truefalseList = new ArrayList<TrueFalse>();
    static ArrayList<Multiple> multipleList = new ArrayList<Multiple>();
    static ArrayList<String> clientAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();


     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

            Connection con; 
            Statement st;
            ResultSet resultSet, resultSet2;

            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

            Socket clientSocket = null;
            ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            ObjectInputStream in = null;
            PrintWriter outScore = null;



            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();

            try {
                  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999); //listening on port 9999
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.out.println("Port Error!");
            }

          System.out.println("Server is ready for connection..");
          clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

          out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
          outScore = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);


          resultSet = st.executeQuery("SELECT No, Question, Answer FROM truefalse");

            //adding true/false questions and their answers to tfList from database
            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                TrueFalse qa = new TrueFalse();
                qa.number=resultSet.getInt(1);
                qa.question=resultSet.getString(2);
                qa.answer=resultSet.getString(3);
                truefalseList.add(qa);
            }

            //writing true-false part to object output stream to send client
//          for(TrueFalse tf : truefalseList)
//              out.writeObject(tf);  


            resultSet2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT No, Question, Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, Ans5, Explanation, Trueans FROM multiple");

            //adding multiple questions and their answers to multList from database
            while (resultSet2.next())
            {
                Multiple qm = new Multiple();
                qm.num=resultSet2.getInt(1);
                qm.question=resultSet2.getString(2);
                qm.answer1=resultSet2.getString(3);
                qm.answer2=resultSet2.getString(4);
                qm.answer3=resultSet2.getString(5);
                qm.answer4=resultSet2.getString(6);
                qm.answer5=resultSet2.getString(7);
                qm.explanation=resultSet2.getString(8);
                qm.trueAns=resultSet2.getString(9);
                multipleList.add(qm);
            }

            //writing mult. part to object output stream to send client
//          for(Multiple mult : multipleList)
//              out.writeObject(mult);  


            out.writeUTF("Server ready");
            out.flush();
            // If we are here, then connection was probably not a portscan
            out.writeObject(truefalseList);
            out.writeObject(multipleList);
            out.flush();

            clientAnswers = (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();

    //      score = (Score)in.readObject();
            // do something with score.
            outScore.println(checkAnswers());
            outScore.flush();

          out.close();
          in.close();
          outScore.close();
          clientSocket.close();
          serverSocket.close();


     }

     static int checkAnswers(){
         int score=0;
         for(int i=0 ; i<clientAnswers.size() ; i++)
         {
             if(i<20)
             {
                 if(clientAnswers.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(truefalseList.get(i).answer))
                 {
                     score=score+3;
                 }

             }
             else
             {
                 int count=0;
                 if(clientAnswers.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(multipleList.get(count).trueAns))
                 {
                     score=score+5;
                     count++;
                 }

             }



         }

         return score;


     }
}
```

Client side: (except gui staff etc..)

```
Socket soket = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedReader inScore = null;


     try {       
            soket = new Socket("localhost",9999);

            in = new ObjectInputStream(soket.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(soket.getOutputStream());
            inScore = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soket.getInputStream()));



            String serverReady = in.readUTF();
             tfList = (ArrayList<TrueFalse>) in.readObject();
             multList = (ArrayList<Multiple>) in.readObject();
    //       score = new Score();
             // prepare the score object
             out.writeObject(userAnswers);
             out.flush();
             // wait for server to process score
             returned_score = inScore.read();
             System.out.println(returned_score);

             // server has processed score and send "Bye".




     } catch (ConnectException ce) {
         System.out.println("Cannot connect to the server!");
     } catch (IOException ie) {
         System.out.println("I/O Error!");
     }

     in.close();
     out.close();
     inScore.close();
     soket.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true way of doing this depends on your non-functional requirements. If you expect non-Java clients to request the (status) data from the database, or clients are behind a proxy, then write your application server as a web-service.

Since you are writing a server that clients will depend on, also think about scalability (deploy the web-service on multiple web-servers behind a load-balancer) and availability (if one web-server goes down, the load-balancer should direct requests to other web-servers that are still up). And don't forget maintainability: ideally you should be able to upgrade/downgrade your application server without clients noticing.

If there are only Java clients (or the data on the line is only question-answer type text like with telnet), then you will need threads and also a database connection pool. I have used [Yapool](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/) to create an "always on" application server like this. It contains a [ServerSocket](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/source/browse/tags/yapool/0.9.1/yapool-core/src/main/java/nl/fw/yapool/socket/SocketAcceptor.java) that you can use/look at to learn this stuff (see also the unit tests). A [database pool](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/source/browse/tags/yapool/0.9.1/yapool-core/src/main/java/nl/fw/yapool/sql/SqlPool.java) implementation is also included.

I have also combined Yapool with a [basic JSP web-service](https://github.com/intercommit/basic-jsp-embed) framework to create a war-file that can be deployed on Tomcat, exposing the application server as a (very simple) web-service. The advantage of a web-service like this is that you do not need to worry (much) about threads and connections: Tomcat does that for you. If you want to take it a step further, I suggest learning about [REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166273/java-rest-frameworks-how-do-i-pick-one).

As for receiving two types of lists: you are inventing your own protocol here and are free to send and receive data to/from the client as long as the client mirrors the server protocol exactly. You can send/receive any kind of object with the ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream as long as it is [serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Lists and Maps are already serializable.

For example server protocol:

```
out.writeUTF("Server ready");
out.flush();
// If we are here, then connection was probably not a portscan
out.writeObject(tfList);
out.writeObject(multipleList);
out.flush();
clientAnswers = (List<String>) in.readObject();
out.writeInt(checkAnswers());
out.writeUTF("Bye");
out.flush();
```

With the following client protocol:

```
String serverReady = in.readUTF();
tfList = (List<TrueFalse>) in.readObject();
multipleList = (List<Multiple>) in.readObject();
out.writeObject(userAnswers);
out.flush();
// wait for server to check answers and return score
int returned_score = in.readInt();
String serverBye = in.readUTF();
// server has processed score and send "Bye".
```

Comment: Appreciate for your generous answer but let me start&learn with beginning.. 
It's done for TF list; sends and works properly.
How can i just make it also work for mult. answer questions list ?
No client request or anything else, i just want to send this two arraylist to client. How can i simply achieve this without or with using thread ?

Comment: Grateful for your answer again. Now I have one more question, if i want to send user's given answers back to the server and control them here then send score back to the client.. How about this situation, i think i should use thread this time ? Do you have any suggestion ? also with simple sample codes ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to demonstrate the bi-directional nature of a socket (you can send and receive, both on server side and client side).

Comment: (UPTADED MY CODE) First i returned user's answers arraylist to server, then control here then send back score integer..  However it always returns 48 :)  i do not understand why..  maybe i cannot return arraylist correctly  or control part maybe wrong :/

Comment: Do not mix different kind of readers/writers, it can probably be done but it will be tricky. Re-use the ObjectInput/OutputStreams you already have. For sending an int, you can use read/writeInt (see updated answer).

Comment: Please accept my answer if it works for you, that way your question will not keep showing up with status unanswered.